# LHR Terminal 5 Transit

Tags: transit

Arriving from US to terminal 5B and connecting (transit) through terminal 5C to Spain (Madrid). Can I proceed directly from 5B to 5C or do we have to go back in to the main terminal 5A and return to 5C?

Comment: I cant be sure as the last time I flew through T5 was several years ago, but Im pretty sure you aren't going to be dumped out into the transit area until after you've taken the train from the remote stand - there was no option before that point during deplaning iirc.  Posting this as a comment because my memory is vague and it was a long time ago.

Comment: I believe you have to go through security and that it only happens in the main terminal, but I haven’t used that route myself so I can’t say for sure.

Comment: Heathrow has a connecting flights [planner](https://www.heathrow.com/connecting-flights). As well as offering generic information if you put in your flight details it should give more detailed information.

Comment: I can't directly answer your question but the various parts of terminal 5 are linked by a free underground [shuttle train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathrow_Terminal_5_Transit). The shuttle, which I have used, is quick so even if you do need to visit the main terminal it shouldn't take very long to travel between the buildings.